# return HTML from ajax request

Tags: php, json, ajax, rest

How to properly return html from an ajax call? Im currently returning html inside json but is there a better way to handle this? How to handle errors and missing arguments for example. Should an ajax request return always JSON?

```
<?=json_encode(array('html' => $res))?>
```

Comment: You can just return the HTML, it's that simple!

Comment: Yes but I want to handle errors also.

Comment: Just return the appropriate HTTP error code (e.g. 400 bad request for missing arguments).

Comment: I need to return other things such as user is not logged in or things like this so I can process them in JS.

Comment: I have seen exactly the structure you are using, with a bit more 'context' so that it's more meaningful: `json_encode(array('results' => 'success', 'html' => $res, 'error' => false))`.   In this way, you would always return a result, and you have space for error messages ('error' could also contain the error message), if desired)

Comment: You can use different error codes to represent different errors (e.g. 401 unauthorized if you're not logged in). If you need very structured data though you should probably stick to returning consistent JSON.

Comment: Yes I will go with JSON because data is more structured than HTML errors.

Comment: Thanks. I will go with this as there are not better solutions. @cale_b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use HandleBars (http://handlebarsjs.com/) or another client side template engine to render JSON into HTML.

Then your JSON will contain only the data.  It will be rendered as HTML and the presentation controlled by CSS.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use a template engine.